# Qual a maneira correta de usar wildcard DNS?

Tags: apache, servidor, dns, virtualhost, wildcard

**Eu preciso que o virtualhost do Apache do meu servidor atenda a seguinte regra:**

1- Caso for domínio.com ou www.domínio.com, então exibe o conteúdo em */var/www/domínio.com/home*

2- Caso for blog.domínio.com, então exibe o conteúdo em */var/www/domínio.com/blog*

3- Caso for um wildcard(*), ou seja, não for nenhum dos dois cima, então exibe o conteúdo em */var/www/domínio.com/plataforma*

**Para que isso fosse possível eu editei meu virtualhost da seguinte forma:**

```
ServerName dominio.com
ServerAlias www.dominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com/public_html/home
```

```
ServerName dominio.com
ServerAlias blog.dominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com/public_html/blog
```

```
ServerName dominio.com
ServerAlias *.dominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com/public_html/plataforma
```

**E minha zona de DNS da seguinte forma:**

@   IN A    111.111.1.111

(*) CNAME   @

**Dúvida:**

Da forma que fiz é uma boa pratica? Caso não, como seria? Tem necessidade de criar um registro na zona de DNS para o *www* e para o *blog*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parte de DNS esta correta, mas os servername estão em conflito, acho que deve ser algo assim:

```
ServerName dominio.com
ServerAlias www.dominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com/public_html/home


ServerName blog.dominio.com
ServerAlias www.blog.dominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com/public_html/blog


ServerName plataforma.dominio.com
ServerAlias *.dominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.com/public_html/plataforma
```

Comment: Fiz como você sugeriu, porém porque o ServerName do wildcard(*) não pode ser igual o do primeiro? Que tipo de conflito poderia ocorrer?

Comment: Você não pode apontar exatamente o mesmo server name para diretórios diferentes...